# How to import csv file to MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, import-csv

I am trying to import `.sql` file of about 0.6 million rows to Mysql workbench, I am following this procedure ( Right click on database --> click on Table Data import Wizard --> browse to my csv -- next -->  next)  but I get the following error

```
`Prepare Import...
Prepare Import done
Import data file....
- Truncate table
- Prepare Import

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 197, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 131, in start_import
    retval = self.module.start(self.stop)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 300, in start
    ret = self.start_import()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 430, in start_import
    self._editor.executeManagementCommand(query, 1)
grt.DBError: ("Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'", 1054)
ERROR: Import data file: ("Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'", 1054)
Failed
`
```

Can someone help me
Also I follow this query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\REPORTING_GENERAL.csv'
INTO TABLE reporting_general FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

but it gives this error

> Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.`

I've checked all the questions on **stackoverflow** but failed, so please don't consider my question as duplicate

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using

Comment: The DUPLICATE should tell you how to fix the `Error Code: 2068.` error

Comment: I am using `8.0.31` version

Comment: So for security reasons MySQL will now only accept a data file from ONE folder/directory. So check your `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file for a parameter called `secure_file_priv=""` You will see a folder/directory name in there. Put your CSV file in there and retry the LOAD

Comment: where are they located?

Comment: What OS are you using

Comment: I am using Windows 10